# Not able to access react state using Context API

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to add alert component to my notebook App so when user logins and make any changes he gets alert at the top, To execute this I used context API, but when I am trying to access the state object to Alert component from AlertContext file, I get this below error

```
alert.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')
```

Here is my Alert and AlertContext files

```
import React from "react"; 
import { useContext } from "react"; 
import { AlertContext } from "../context/notes/AlertContext";
    
export const Alert = (props) => { 
const { alerts } = useContext(AlertContext);
return (
        <div>
          <div
            className={`alert alert-${alerts.type}  alert-dismissible fade show`}
            role="alert"
            role="alert"
          >
            {alerts.message}
          </div>
        </div>   
      ); 
};
```

---

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { AlertContext } from './AlertContext'


const AlertState = (props) => {

  const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState({ message: null, type: null });

  const setMsg = (msg,type) =>
  {
    setAlerts({ message: msg, type: type });
    setTimeout(() =>
    {
      setAlerts({ message: null, type: null })
    },1500);
  }
  return (
      <AlertContext.Provider  value={setMsg , alerts}>
          {props.children}
      </AlertContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default AlertState
```

Comment: Are you wrapping the `Alert` component within your provider, in this case the `AlertState` component?

Comment: And it seems like you're missing brackets on this line: `<AlertContext.Provider  value={setMsg , alerts}>`, it's supposed to be `<AlertContext.Provider  value={{setMsg , alerts}}>`

Comment: Good observation, thank you for your time

Comment: In order for your component (in your case the `Alert` component) to be able to use React context, it has to have the `Provider` as its parent (in your case `AlertContext.Provider`, or more specifically your `AlertState` component). I mean do you have something like this in your component hierarchy: `<AlertState><Alert /></AlertState>`?

Comment: Yes, I have this one, otherwise I would have got some different error.

Comment: You wouldn't get a different error, you would get that exact error. Can you provide the code of your `AlertContext` file? I think that the issue probably lies there. Are you maybe creating your context without a default value? Something like this: `const AlertContext = React.createContext()`?

Comment: Try to create it with a default value: `const AlertContext = React.createContext({ alerts: { message: null, type: null },  setMsg: () => {} });`

Comment: Yes, Thank you my error got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Try it

```
<AlertContext.Provider value={{setMsg,alerts}}>
         {props.children}
     </AlertContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following check in your Alert component beacuse initially the 'alerts' object is going to be null. That's why it is giving this error. Adding this check will resolve the error.

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import AlertContext from "../context/AlertContext";

const Alert = () => {
  const {alerts} = useContext(AlertContext);

  return alerts !== null ? (
    <div
      className={`alert alert-${alerts.type} alert-dismissible fade show`}
      role="alert"
    >
      {alerts.message}
    </div>
  ) : (
    <></>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```